# 02 olds intrigue...is it a transmission problem or something else

Tags: oldsmobile, intrigue

.will only go 20 mph in drive and revs up...an 35 mph in 3rd an revs to 4000rpms...it shifts from 1st to 3rd an in reverse. Whats wrong with my car.? Is it a transmission problem or something else.

Comment: Have you checked the transmission fluid level?

Comment: First to third?, it time for a trans overhaul.